# Node.js + Express + i18next how manage two languages same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multilingual, i18next

in my Node.js + Express + i18next app I would like to keep separate frontend and backend languages. I already managed to keep separate the login session data, so that I can login as normal user in the frontend and as administrator in the backend at the same time and 
independently:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
...
 app
    .use('/admin', session({
    ...
    cookie: {
            path: '/admin',
        },
    name: 'adminSessionID',
    ...
    }))
    .use('/', session({
    ...
    cookie: {
            path: '/',
        },
    name: 'sessionID',
    ...
```

Now I need to do the same with i18next and languages. What can I do? I tried creating 2 i18next instances but the cookie created is always only the last one defined and, even worst, if I change language via query string, it changes both in front and backend...

Any advice could be usefull, thank you

Comment: Check out next-i18next, which supports all the cases. https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next

Comment: Thanks but I don't use Next, shouldn't I use i18next with Express?

Comment: Ha, sorry from some reason I saw next.js... you can take inspiration from next-i18next implementation, it uses express & i18next :]